# Axibase Time-Series Database data sampling maximum rate

Tags: time-series, axibase

I am using Axibase Time Series Database Community Edition, version 10379. I try to store my data that comes from a  force sensor and save it every 2 milliseconds, how can I configure the portal to accept this time resolution?
I made an attempt to send the data in that rate by using an Arduino board with WiFi shield but the TCP connection disconnected after sending a little data.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of *Axibase* but if your input comes too fast you could just write a buffer program that'll batch-insert into your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time resolution in Axibase Time-Series Database is 1 millisecond by default, so the problem is probably occurring for other reasons such as:

- Invalid timestamp
- Missing end-of-line character at the end of the `series` command
- Same timestamp for multiple commands with the same entity/metric/tags. For example, these commands are duplicates and one of the them will be discarded:

  `series ms:1445762625574 e:e-1 m:m-1=100`

  `series ms:1445762625574 e:e-1 m:m-1=125`
- Overflow of receiving queue in ATSD. This can occur if ingestion rate is higher than disk write speed for long period of time. Open ATSD portal in the GUI and check the top right chart if rejected_count metric is greater than zero. This can be addressed by changing default configuration settings.

[image: ATSD portal]

- Other reasons specified in https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/api/data/#errors

I would recommend starting netcat in server mode and recording data from the Arduino board to file to see exactly what commands are sent into ATSD.

1. Stop ATSD with `./atsd-tsd.sh stop`
2. Launch netcat in server mode and record received data to command.log file:

   `netcat -lk 8081 > command.log`
3. Restart Arduino and send some data into ATSD (now netcat). Review command.log file
4. Start ATSD with `./atsd-tsd.sh start`

Disclosure: I work for Axibase.

Comment: Thank you very much, kindly can I change the decay resolution of portal that show the plotted data?, now the minimum interval is 1 hour, with milliseconds data rate i could not plot the output signal in all details.                         Regards

Comment: You can modify the interval length for displaying data on charts using timespan setting. See example here: http://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/e491b1ba. The timespan setting can be customized for each widget separately. You can also use mouse wheel to zoom in/out of the timeline.